# Monodromy with respect to a given covering.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-topology, riemannian-geometry, covering-spaces

I want to read the topic monodromy for covering spaces.

I have seen many books on algebraic topology but could not find a book which explains this topic in detail.

Please suggest me some books or notes on this topic. It will be a great help.

Comment: I suggest that you add the [tag:reference-request]  tag to your question.

Comment: What precisely are you looking for with regards to monodromy?

Comment: Have you tried googling the phrase 'monodromy for covering spaces'? :-)

Comment: @Thorgott, I am looking for covering sapce

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, thanks

Comment: @EvansGambit, yes I have but could not find

Comment: @BhawanaDey If you provide more context as to what you are reading which prompted the necessity to look up 'monodromy for covering spaces' or a specific result you are trying to understand, probably you will get a more fruitful response.